# Cannot set cookie in browser but working with postman

Tags: go, cookies, browser

I am trying to set a cookie using go in the chrome browser but can only get it to set in postman.

The cookie successfully sets in postman but is simply not setting in chrome with no error. 
I have set CORS as default using this package https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors as I have had issues with CORS requests in the past and this seemed to solve the issue.
I set the cookie using:

```
c.SetCookie(
    "TOKEN",
    tokenString,
    3600,
    "/",
    "localhost",
    false,
    true)
```

I have tried replacing localhost with http://127.0.0.1 which again works in postman but not chrome or firefox. I have also tried setting the cookie with the http package instead but this has failed in the same way.

**EDIT** I have also tried domain as blank ("") but this has the same outcome.

Comment: What is type type of `c` in the code snippet?

Comment: c is of type *gin.Context

Answer (score 1):

You passed `true` to the `secure` argument of [SetCookie](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.SetCookie) but you're sending the cookie to an insecure http address.

As per [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies):

```
A secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol.
```

Comment: Sorry yes, that is from me doing the try every combination phase. It still doesn't work with that as false but I will change that in the question thank you!

Comment: Is this issue is resolved? I am also facing the same.

Comment: had anybody success solving this issue?

Comment: From the MDN docs you linked (they have likely been updated since you posted your answer): "A cookie with the Secure attribute is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. It's never sent with unsecured HTTP (except on localhost)." The OP is using localhost, so the `Secure` flag shouldn't have any effect and the cookie should be sent anyway.